# Concatenation PHP preg_replace function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, string, concatenation

I'm using Ajax to transmit JS variables to my script PHP in order to change the background color. Can you help me to reach this goal ? I don't know how to use concatenation here and use $mavariable.

```
$mavariable=$_POST['background'];
echo $mavariable; //Return the string blue

$backgroundcolor='background-color:green;';
$background='/background-color:yellow;/'; //How to use $mavariable here ? 

$contenuMod=preg_replace($background, $backgroundcolor,$lineContent); //This works if i'm not using $mavariable
```

Comment: Please elaborate more. How you use `$mavariable`?

Comment: To replace the string "yellow"

Answer (score 1):

Simply `concatenate` the variable with the `string` where you need. Try with -

```
$background='/background-color:" . $mavariable . ";/';
```

Comment: You need to use " _OR_ ', not mixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.`(dot) oprater you can concatenate two string or value as show below

`$background='background-color:'.$mavariable;`

hop this will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To complete sgt's answer, you should change your regex to handle more colors(litteral style):

```
background-color:\w+;
```

Or you can go for the hex style regex:

```
background-color:#[A-Fa-f0-9]+;
```

Answer (score 0):

We are close to the truth ... This is the generate code :

```
    blue  // Result of echo $mavariable
    Chaine nouvelle :body{     
    Chaine nouvelle :    background-color:".$mavariable.";
    Chaine nouvelle : font-size: 18px;
    Chaine nouvelle :    font-family: cursive;
    Chaine nouvelle :}}}
```